# Check for duplicates in arrays with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in my table that will always contain an array of three items (they come from 3 selects with the same items that the user chooses from). I need to make a query that will return if any user has selected the same combination of 3 items that another user has selected too, doesn't matter the order he chose them in.

So I have 3 selects with the same content in them, the user needs to chose an item from each one (it's validated so all of them are different) and I need to check if that combination has been chosen before or not.

In my database the array looks like this:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:8:"item1";i:1;s:8:"item3";i:2;s:8:"item5"}
```

The database will have many users so I'm afraid that checking this will be very resource intensive, what is the best way to approach it?

Comment: Sorry, but obviously the best way is _not_ to store the arrays in serialized form exactly because it is completely inefficient later when you have to compare them. You need to select, process and compare each line one by one. That won't scale. The only thing you could try is: only store the serialized arrays _after_ having sorted them. That way you can compare them as strings right in the where clause. That _would_ scale and work, since the sorted arrays serialized representation would be identical for a repeated selection.

Comment: That I can do, certainly, it didn't even occured to me

Comment: Better yet, don't store your data in serialised form.  Instead, [normalize your schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) so that you can take full advantage of the relational capabilities of the RDBMS.

Comment: I can't I'm using wordpress for this and that would be going against the schema of wordpress and making it incompatible with wordpress functions, but I agree serialized arrays are not the best way to go